# Serializing/Deserializing JSON to TypeScript with conversions

Tags: json, typescript

I am trying to serialize TypeScript objects to JSON and vice-versa. While converting, certain fields have to be transformed, e.g. `Date` objects to ISO 8601 strings, enumerations to values required by the wire format, etc. I am currently creating type definitions for both the TypeScript object and the JSON object (trying to avoid typing the JSON object as `any`). Is there a better pattern for doing this?

**Example**

TypeScript object:

```
{
  name: 'John Smith',
  title: 'Sr. Developer',
  dob: new Date('1990-05-01T09:00:00Z');
}
```

JSON object:

```
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "title": "Sr. Developer",
  "dob": "1990-05-01T09:00:00Z";
}
```

Here's the code to serialize/deserialize + the type definitions for the two formats:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    title: string;
    dob: Date;
}

interface JsonPerson {
    name: string;
    title: string;
    dob: string; // ISO 8601 format
}

function serialize(person: Person): JsonPerson {
    const { dob, ...rest } = person;
    return {
        dob: dob.toISOString(),
        ...rest
    }
}

function deserialize(jsonPerson: JsonPerson): Person {
    const { dob, ...rest } = jsonPerson;
    return {
        dob: new Date(dob),
        ...rest
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think you'd only need the deserialization code, since serialization should just be `JSON.stringify(Person)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `Date.prototype.toJSON` [already uses the ISO string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) so you don't need to do `dob.toISOString()`

What you have is fine and generally what I prefer as well (explicit serialization / deserialization). I also have a [video on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFTL0HgNoaQ).

But if you want to use a serialization library here are two that I recommend for *TypeScript* that use decorators:

- Part of the mobx ecosystem (which is another thing I love) https://github.com/mobxjs/serializr
- A less popular but equally impressive library : https://github.com/danrevah/typeserializer

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, Basarat, and nice video on this subject! BTW, I am also a fan of MobX and in fact have have written a router based on it: https://nareshbhatia.github.io/mobx-state-router/

Comment: Just confirming, while automatic serialization of dates works, automatic deserialization of strings to dates will not happen, correct? I will need the `new Date(dob)` during deserialization.

Comment: ` automatic deserialization of strings to dates will not happen, correct? I will need the new Date(dob) during deserialization`  Correct 